# Rescale knitr plot output in an .Rwn document to fit to the whole page in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, plot, knitr, resize

Setup:

- I have an .Rwn file
- I use the beamer document class
- I knit the .Rnw file using knitr

Problem: I want to resize the plot produced by the following code to fit to the whole page (preferably not completely but with some minimal margin of about 0.5cm). Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Knitr setup              
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.align="center", fig.height=3.7, out.width="\\textwidth")
opts_knit$set(out.format = "latex")
@

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<include=FALSE>>=
if(!require(ggplot2)) install.packages("ggplot2")
require(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(n = 100),
                  "y" = runif(n = 100, min = -1, max = 1))
@

<<echo = FALSE>>=
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "<A plot>",
       subtitle = "<A subtitle>",
       caption = "Source: <A source>")
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

**Question: how do I get the output plot to fit to the whole page?**

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not need to set `out.width`:  it is set up by default to the maximal allowable width.
2. You need to set `fig.height` and `fig.width` correctly.  Log says that in beamer

   - \textwidth=307.28987pt
   - \textheight=244.6939pt

Therefore let us set up `knitr` output dimensions correspondingly in inches

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Knitr setup              
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.align="center", fig.height=3.3, fig.width=4.2)
opts_knit$set(out.format = "latex")
@

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
<<include=FALSE>>=
if(!require(ggplot2)) install.packages("ggplot2")
require(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame("x" = rnorm(n = 100),
                  "y" = runif(n = 100, min = -1, max = 1))
@

<<echo = FALSE>>=
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "<A plot>",
       subtitle = "<A subtitle>",
       caption = "Source: <A source>")
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The resulting figure occupies the slide up to margins:

[image]